# Going back and forth between UIViewController while keeping the states of the views

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers, `PlayViewController` and `ShopViewController`. 
The goal is to go from `PlayViewController` to `ShopViewController`, and back.

To go to the shopController I use this code:

```
        UIStoryboard* mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        ShopViewController* vc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShopViewController"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [vc setGameLevelManager:[[playViewController getCentralUIManager] getGameManager]];
        [vc setUIViewControllerOrigin:nil PlayerViewController:playViewController];
        [playViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The code above works, user jumps from the `PlayViewController` to the `ShopViewController`.
Now when jumping back from the `ShopViewController` to `PlayViewController` I use the following code:

```
        playViewController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:playViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The Code above does go back to the `PlayViewController`, but call for the `viewDidLoad` and re-initiate the view from the beginning. Thing is that when i call `ShopViewController` from `PlayViewController`, I have additional window shown in the View, namely the `LevelFailure` view. When `ViewDidLoad`, it completely forget about what was displayed when the user went to `ShopViewController`.

I am sure there is a way to go back to `PlayViewController` and have the states , and views back how they were , but I could not identify the approach yet.

If you would have any thoughts about the matter, there would be more than welcome!

Comment: iOS uses ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). When a view "completely forgets" something, it means the value it "forgot" was no longer referenced and it was "thrown out". To keep that from happening, you'll want to either pass the value as a parameter when you segue or save it somewhere so it can be retrieved later (perhaps `NSUserDefaults`?).

Comment: instead of `presentViewController` use `popViewControllerAnimated`